# The votes cast count are not matching

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My votes casts on my votes tab is not matching the Civic Duty badge's shown vote count. I'am expected to see "74 Votes Cast" instead of "70 Votes Cast". It is displaying wrongly. It is now 2 hours from now. 
[image: The votes cast on the votes tab are displaying wrongly]

However, the Badges menu at the Civic Duty badge also shows my vote casts as 74. What's happening?

Comment: There is a certain linguistics breakdown in your question. What do you mean from "It's now 2 hours for now"? 0 does not equal 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, they count different things, and to summarize:

- **Number on the badge tracking**: Votes that have been cast.
- **Number on the right panel**: Votes that *"are cached and eventually added to your running total [...]"*.
- **Number on the left**: Votes that exclude e.g. those on deleted posts.

See this question for more: [Why are there three different numbers of votes cast in my profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290333/1012553)